# ContextMenuStrip item selection width/height

Tags: c#, .net

[image]

Above is a picture of my contextmenustrip item.

When I hover my mouse over said item, it puts a blue rectangle around both the picture and text; however, this rectangle is very long in width aka the amount of space after the 't' is needed to see full blue selected rectangle.

My question is how can I change the size of the item text selection aka width?

Comment: Undelete your question, post your comment and then delete it again? funny kid...Then you may want to explain Why I get null when I put `GetElementById` directly after `DocumentText=.... (or Navigate.. same...)` and how it works with the code I posted.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335542/c-sharp-htmlelement-get-select-id

Comment: I realized before you put ur answer and decided to delete it. u mad?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

Change AutoSize for your toolstripmenuitem to false!

then change the width!

TA DA!